# Calculate sum of a "Strings" list after parse JAVA

Tags: java

I want to calculate the sum of the content in my list. This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        ArrayList nummer = new ArrayList(); // make new list
        while (true) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // start scanner

            System.out.print("Voer uw naam in: ");

            String naam = input.nextLine(); // scanner waiting for input + enter
            if (naam.equals("0")) {
                System.out.println("Wrong, exit!");
                input.close();

                 for (Object item : nummer) { // foreach-loop
                     System.out.print(item + "\n");
                     i = Integer.parseInt((String) item);
                     }
                 System.out.println(sum = i);
                break;
            } else { 
                nummer.add(naam);
                continue;
            }

        }



    }
}
```

As you see the user can input numbers but it will be saved as a string so i parsed it. But after that i try to make the calculation it takes only the last item of the list. Is there a way to take all inputs for calculating the sum?

Comment: Are you sure about the `sum = i` expression?

Comment: Your ArrayList should be using generic types if you're using Java 1.7+. Also, you should instantiate your Scanner object only once. Move it outside your while loop.

Comment: Nevermind, found the problem: i += Integer.parseInt((String) item); I had to add + before the = xD

Comment: btw: There is a method scanner.nextInt () which you could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a modified portion of your code. As others have pointed out, you should only initialize the scanner once. Also, the continue statement is redundant where you had it since the loop will continue anyway.

```
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList nummer = new ArrayList(); // make new list
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // start scanner
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Voer uw naam in: ");

        String naam = input.nextLine(); // scanner waiting for input + enter
        if (naam.equals("0")) {
            System.out.println("Wrong, exit!");
            input.close();

             for (Object item : nummer) { // foreach-loop
                 System.out.print(item + "\n");
                 i = Integer.parseInt((String) item);
                                     sum += i;
                     }
             System.out.println(sum);
            break;
        } else { 
            nummer.add(naam);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

After the line `i = Integer.parseInt((String) item);`, you need to add i to your sum. So add the following line right after that:

`sum= sum + i;`

And then just print sum as

`System.out.println(sum);`

Comment: I think you meant to write sum+=i